# EF Core 6 inheritance

Tags: c#, inheritance, entity-framework-core, ef-core-6.0

I have these entities in EF Core 6

The image show *Inheritance*(for base - inherited classes with same latter A or B) and *Relations* (for classes A B and C).

[image: How it look]

This is how it looks in code:

```
public class BaseA { }

public class InheritedA1 : BaseA {}
public class InheritedA2 : BaseA {}

public class C 
{
    public InheritedA2 A2 { get; set; }
}

public class BaseB 
{
    public BaseA BaseA { get; set; }
} 

public class InheritedB1 : BaseB 
{
    public InheritedA1 A1 { get; set; }
}

public class InheritedB2 : BaseB 
{
    public C Some { get; set; }
}
```

Problem: I try to create

```
new InheritedB1 { A1 = new InheritedA1() }
```

but when storing, EF Core doesn't understand that Fields A1 from InheritedB1 and BaseA from BaseB are connected. How can I configure my model for this?

Comment: Your model (/drawing) is wrong. `InheritedB1` and `InheritedB2` can't inherit from two classes

Comment: @Flydog57 Yep. You are right. It show Inheritance(for base - inherited classes with same latter A or B) and Relations (for classes A B and C).

Comment: This drawing is not clear @CMaker.  You're connecting every single relations with a common arrow.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I understood from you design is that this structure looks like `Bridge` pattern. You are trying to connect two Hierarchy of entities in some way. But this is not `EFCore` problem with inheritance I think, It's a kind of design issue.

There are auxiliary relation between some entities. As you pointed out you have a `InheritedB1` which has relations with two instance of `BaseA` one of them is `BaseA` (from `BaseB` the father of `InheritedB1`) and the second one is `InheritedA1` which you know it as `A1`.

So you should Fill it. to get rid of `SQL` Errors.

```
public class BaseA 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class InheritedA1 : BaseA 
{
    public string ExtendedBaseA { get; set; }
}

public class InheritedA2 : BaseA 
{
    public string ExtendedBaseA { get; set; }
}

public class C
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    
    public virtual InheritedA2 A2 { get; set; }

    public string IndependentClass { get; set; }
}

public class BaseB
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual BaseA BaseA { get; set; }
}

public class InheritedB1 : BaseB
{
    public string ExtendedBaseB { get; set; }

    public virtual InheritedA1 A1 { get; set; }
}

public class InheritedB2 : BaseB
{
    public string ExtendedBaseB { get; set; }

    public virtual C Some { get; set; }
}
```

I have added some extra fields to track possible issues.

and here is my configurations:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Entity<BaseA>().ToTable("BaseA");
        builder.Entity<InheritedA1>().ToTable("InheritedA1");
        builder.Entity<InheritedA2>().ToTable("InheritedA2");

        builder.Entity<BaseB>().ToTable("BaseB");
        builder.Entity<BaseB>().HasOne(P => P.BaseA);
        
        builder.Entity<C>().ToTable("C");
        builder.Entity<C>().HasOne(P => P.A2);

        builder.Entity<InheritedB1>().ToTable("InheritedB1");
        builder.Entity<InheritedB1>().HasOne(P => P.A1);

        builder.Entity<InheritedB2>().ToTable("InheritedB2");
        builder.Entity<InheritedB2>().HasOne(P => P.Some);

        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
```

And here is my usage:

```
var a = new InheritedB1 
{ 
    A1 = new InheritedA1()
    {
        Name = "hujhj",
        ExtendedBaseA = "WW"
    },
    BaseA = new BaseA() // you have missed to filling this
    {
        Name = "ghjgjh"
    },
    Name = "A",
    ExtendedBaseB = "AAA"
};
schoolContext.ExtendedB1.Add(a);
schoolContext.SaveChanges();
```

I have used `Table-Per-Type` (aka `TPT`) strategy for inheritances.
But I don't think that you might have problems with other strategies.
I think you should focus on your design.

**Edit**
you can do this:

```
public class InheritedB1 : BaseB
{
    public string ExtendedBaseB { get; set }

    public virtual InheritedA1 A1 
    { 
      get => _a1; 
      set
      {
         _a1 = value;
         BaseA = _a1.Clone();
      }
    }

    private InheritedA1 _a1;
}
```

But it's not meaningful.

Comment: The problem is I want the BaseA property fills automatically from the A1 property (the same intance). As a navigation property works